# i am not getting confirmation mail when a user fill my form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a website. i want to get form details from my customer...
i am preparing some code. The code works good on some hosting panel but not working in my hosting panel.
i think some functions are not supporting my hosting.
i report the hosting provider but there is no good solution.
can any one solve this...
Thanks in advance

my advertisement.html form is looking like this

```
<form action="advertisement-form.php" method="post" class="comment-form row-fluid" data-validate="parsley">

                            <p>
                                <label for="name" class="span2">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="span10" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="name" required >
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="email" class="span2">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="span10" placeholder="Your E-mail" id="email" name="email" required >
                            </p>

                                <p>
                                <label for="name" class="span2">Your Ad Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="span10" placeholder="Ad Title" id="ad_title" name="ad_title" required >
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="site" class="span2">Target URL</label>
                                <input type="text" name="target_url" id="target_url" class="span10" data-type="url" required>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="site" class="span2">Banner URL</label>
                                <input type="text" name="banner_url" id="banner_url" class="span10" data-type="url" required>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="site" class="span2">Payment Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="payment_email" id="payment_email" class="span10" data-type="url" required>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="mess" class="span2">Message</label>
                                <textarea name="message" class="span10" data-trigger="keyup" data-rangelength="[20,1000]"></textarea>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="button button-load large-button offset2 span4">
                            </p>
                        </form>
```

and my form processing is looking like this, named with advertisement-form.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "New Advertisement for Website";


 // validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['ad_title']) ||

    !isset($_POST['target_url']) ||

    !isset($_POST['banner_url']) ||

    !isset($_POST['payment_email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['message'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}



$name = $_POST['name']; // required



$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$ad_title = $_POST['ad_title']; // required

$target_url = $_POST['target_url']; // required

$banner_url = $_POST['banner_url']; // required

$payment_email = $_POST['payment_email']; // not required

$message = $_POST['message']; // required



$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Ad Title: ".clean_string($ad_title)."\n";

$email_message .= "Target URL: ".clean_string($target_url)."\n";

$email_message .= "Banner URL: ".clean_string($banner_url)."\n";

$email_message .= "Payment Email: ".clean_string($payment_email)."\n";

$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

when a user fill the form he got success message. but i am not receiving confirmation mail. this script working some hosting panels, not in my hosting panel.can any one solve this...

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest this as a try, ending each line with `\r\n` and also adding a *To* header (redundant as it might seem). Also, declaring `charset=utf-8` in the header should be enough.

```
  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
  // Additional headers
  // This might look redundant but some services REALLY favor it being there.
  $headers .= "To: $to_fullname <$to_email>\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $from_fullname <$from_email>\r\n";
```

Also the function is `die` not `died`

Comment: see the link. That contains entire explanation regarding PHP mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: same code works on another hosting ... i don't know what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1 - change

```
 died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
```

to

```
 die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
```

2- remove @ before mail function. As using @ before any statement will suppress errors if anything goes wrong. So if you remove this.. It would be easy to troubleshoot. 
Follow the 2 steps above and try again. If you see any error, paste them here